# How can I get FULL html code via Webkit.net

Tags: html, ajax, webkit.net

The website use ajax to load some data.When DocumentCompleted,I only get the html code without ajax data.

How to get the ajax data through webkit.net?

Thanks.

Comment: Webkit.net would have to be able to interpret JavaScript, which I doubt it can.

Answer (score 0):

I've just recently fought with this myself and have what should be a working solution. I've not tried it with ajax, but I have used it after creating and appending DOM elements from C# and it produces the full code where DocumentText only produces the original unmodified HTML.

```
var fullHTML = webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML")
```

The only limitation to this method that I've seen is that it does not include the doctype tag if there is one, but everything else is there.